# How long was John the Baptist in the wilderness as a child?

Tags: john-the-baptist

How long did Elizabeth hide John the Baptist in a cave when Herod was killing babies?

Britannica.com says:

> In 27/28 or 28/29 John attained prominence, not as a priest but as a prophet. He was active in the region of the lower Jordan valley, from “Aenon near Salim” (near modern Nāblus) to a point east of Jericho. His austere camel’s hair garment was the traditional garb of the prophets, and his diet of locusts and wild honey represented either strict adherence to Jewish purity laws or the ascetic conduct of a Nazirite (a Jew especially vowed to God’s service). His mission was addressed to all ranks and stations of Jewish society. His message was that God’s judgment on the world was imminent and that, to prepare for this judgment, the people should repent their sins, be baptized, and produce appropriate fruits of repentance."

The article [The Cave Where Saint Elizabeth Hid With Saint John the Baptist and the Tomb of Saint Elizabeth](https://www.johnsanidopoulos.com/2021/06/the-cave-where-saint-elizabeth-hid-with.html?m=1) says:

> When the Lord Jesus had been born and Herod began to slaughter the children of Bethlehem, he sent men to find and kill the son of Zechariah – for Herod had heard all that had happened to Zechariah, and how John has been born. Upon seeing the soldiers coming, Elizabeth took John into her arms – he was a year and a half old at that time – fled from the house with him, and ran to a rocky and desolate place. When she saw the soldiers following her, she cried out to the mountain: “O Mountain of God, receive a mother with her child!” and the rock opened and hid the mother and child. Then Herod, enraged that the child John had not been slain, ordered Zechariah be slain before the altar. The blood of Zacharias was spilled on the marble and dried solid as stone, and remained as a witness as Herod’s evil deed. In the place where Elizabeth hid with John a cave opened, water flowed out of it, and a fruit-bearing palm grew, all by the power of God. Forty days after the death of Zechariah, the blessed Elizabeth died. The child John remained in the wilderness, fed by an angel and protected by God’s providence, until the day he appeared at the Jordan.

The book of the Protevalgeion says that:

> Elizabeth also, hearing that her son John was about to be searched for, took him and went up unto the mountains, and looked around for a place to hide him; 4 And there was no secret place to be found. 5 Then she groaned within herself, and said, O mountain of the Lord, receive the mother with the child. 6 For Elizabeth could not climb up. 7 And instantly the mountain was divided and received them. 8 And there appeared to them an angel of the Lord, to preserve them.

Further reading says that Elizabeth died and an Angel fed him but the bible says he was in the wilderness until he was announced in public... help I'm confused.  In some aspects, the story in the protevengelion makes the story of John the Baptist similar to that of the woman and dragon of Revelation. But to connect the  2 the lost book would be more accurate than the gospels considering they indicate that he was raised in the temple as a prophet. But also says he was in the wilderness but doesn't give a time frame except for the adult part of 40 days. How would an unknown orphaned 1.5-year-old baby be able to go be taught in the temple (blood rights only)? Help me sort this out.

It would make sense that she hid him for 1260 days (revelation)  then he was raised in the temple and was led to the wilderness for 40 days where he was announced.

Comment: This is a real mix-up of encyclopedic superstition, scripture and unrelated scriptures (from Revelation) being paired irrelevantly. Major clarity and detail (and focus) issues, in my own view, need to be dealt with to sort it all out. Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to how this, an _hermeneutic_ site opeartes.

Answer (score 1):

The principal source for this narrative regarding John the Baptist is the so-called Gospel of James (aka the Protoevangelium). It was written in the 2nd century and relied (in part) on the Gospels of Matthew & Luke.

The Gospel of James is a problematic text:

- It is pseudepigraphal (the person writing it claimed to be someone he was not)
- The text was [condemned by Innocent I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_James#cite_note-FOOTNOTEBetsworth2015169-31) in the 5th century
- The text was written long after the eyewitnesses to Jesus' (and John's) life were gone. This does not mean it contains no historical truth, but it should not be treated as a primary source as the 4 canonical Gospels are.

The narrative regarding John that is presented in the Gospel of James is neither well-grounded nor well-substantiated historically. It could be better described as hagiography than history.

While the Gospel of James may well have been influenced by the Book of Revelation, it is generally considered unreliable historically & theologically.

*How long did Elizabeth hide John the Baptist in a cave when Herod was killing babies?*

We do not know that Elizabeth hid John in a cave, let alone for how long. John and his family did not live in Bethlehem, so it is highly unlikely they would have even been in scope for Herod's murderous edict.

Comment: Good answer containing helpful information. +1 :)